# Graphic card making more noise Idle than when using it

Tags: graphics-card, fan

I have a problem with my graphic card where it's making noise when Idle because it's using only one fan. It makes almost way less noise at 80°C (using both fans) but at 30°C it's really unpleasant when trying to use the computer normally. In the last days (I think it's getting worse over time) I was lauching graphic card stress tests in background just to be able to work on my things. The noise at 30°C isn't special, it's just the first fan going very fast.

What can I do to fix that? Can I force the graphic card to always use both fan? Looking at how fast the first fan goes when I'm Idle, what could cause that?

I have a [Zotac GTX 760 AMP](https://www.zotac.com/gb/product/graphics_card/gtx-760-amp)

Comment: If it's only using one fan, and it didn't always use just one fan, time to replace the fan or the card

Comment: Aye. Also, do you hear the GPU chip of the fan on the graphics card. There is quite a difference. [GPU] is just a single chip, or part of an APU. It is not the card or any components on the card.

Comment: @Ramhound I don't know if it was using only one fan before. I think it was using it but normally, now it's running too fast

Comment: Like I said replace the fan or replace the card. Tweaking just the single fan will result in your GPU overheating (it's running at that speed in order to cool it)

Comment: @Hennes I don't really understand, I edited my question to include the card. All I can hear are fans

Comment: The GPU is just one chip on the card. I is very doubtfull that you can hear that one single chip. Sadly many people write [GPU] when they mean [graphics card]. It might help to think of it like a car, you posted a question tagged [car], [fan]  and [fuel reservoir], with the text 'the cooling fan is very loud'. I am mostly wondering why it would be tagged [fuelling reservoir'..

Note that this is not just you. It seems common to confuse them.

Comment: Just to make it clear. I am targeting a **lot** of wrong tags here on [SU]. I have been doing that for years. It is not just your post.

As for a solution: I think @Ramhound nailed it. If it did not do so before that something changed, Probably with the second fan which does not seem to sping up at low speeds, causing the second fan to run into noisy high speeds. Replacing the fan is probably the right solution.

Comment: Your suppose to hear the fans, to a certain point, if one of the fan isn't working logic would indicate that the other fan would have to run faster to cool the card. So either fix the broken fan or replace the entire graphic card one with passive cooling.  No; My suggestion really isn't answer quality basically telling you to repair or replace the card you have which you probably thought of already

Comment: It's the first fan that make noisy sound. So changing the first one? It's stupid because the first one does not make any noise when the second one is being use. And the second one does not seem to have any problem. It runs when It is needed. I have integrated graphics that I can use to work (programming/text) and since it does not make noise when I'm playing, I would prefer just to disable my GPU when I do not need it. Is it a viable option? I just disabled it now but even if it's not being used it's currently running fast...